# dissolving powder

Tags: mixtures

I have small amount of rosemary herb powder mixed in a cup of water and it's only party dissolving. I was wondering if there is another powder that can be added to this water solution and dissolve the rosemary completely?

I would like to avoid using rosemary essential oil as it has a certain scent that is different than the scent of the full leaf powder. I wish to only use the necessary ingredients to make the rosemary powder fully dissolve. The goal is to make the rosemary powder not visible when holding the glass of water up to the light.

Comment: Im tempted to flag this as "homework". ;) Why do you think it should dissolve?

Comment: Do you know the difference between a suspension and a solution? Does flour dissolve in water? Sugar?

Comment: The goal is unattainable.

Answer (score 2):

The dry and powdered parts of former bodies of living things are not soluble without destruction of their chemical and structural nature.

The only achievable way is to prepare such a fine powder that the difference between its suspension and clear liquid does not bother the end user. Surfactants and thickeners may stabilize the suspension, but it would be still suspension.

Alternative achievable way could be the powder extraction by high percentage food grade ethyl alcohol, keeping the filtered extract and adding it to water.

Comment: You could add a surfactant and/or thickener to make and keep a suspension more stable.

Comment: @James Gaidis  Sure, you can. But it would be still suspension.